# Numerical stability of Simplex method

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, optimization, linear-programming, na.numerical-analysis

The simplex algorithm is often treated either within real arithmetic, or in the discrete world with exact computations. However, it seems to be implemented most often with floating-point arithmetic.

This leads to the question whether the simplex algorithm should be regarded as a numerical algorithm, in particular how round-off errors affect the computation. I am not interested in practical implementations, but rather in theoretical foundations.

Are you aware of any research on this issue?

Comment: If you are interested in implementations of the simplex algorithm, then I would suggest you to ask the question in http://www.or-exchange.com/

Comment: @Snowie: This question is less about practical implementation but rather about theoretical aspects. There has been work in theoretical foundations of numerical analysis, and I wonder whether it has affected the theory of the simplex algorithm. Anyways, thanks for the link still.

Comment: I have edited the question to make my interest clearer.

Comment: Have you looked at [smoothed analysis](http://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0111050)? This work not only addresses the average-case running time, but also the average-case stability.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is research on this issue.

[The Simplex Method is Not Always Well Behaved](http://www.ia.pw.edu.pl/~wogrycza/publikacje/artykuly/mylinalg.pdf), Wlodzimierz Ogryczak

[retroLP, An Implementation of the Standard Simplex Method](http://cis.poly.edu/rvslyke/implmnt.pdf), Gavriel Yarmish and Richard Van Slyke

[A Numerically Stable Form of the Simplex Algorithm](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379573900475), Philip E. Gill and Walter Murray

You might also be interested in the [revised simplex method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revised_simplex_method).  This method can take advantage of matrix sparsity; it doesn't keep a representation of the entire matrix.
This thesis was of great interest to me: [A Comparison of Simplex Method Algorithms](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/Morgan/index.htm).